# How do I run 'rails server' inside a shell script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that automatically runs my rails app in a virtual machine.

My script code is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin'
cd /home/lgdelacruz/SampleApp
rails server
```

But for some reason it doesn't see all the dependencies. this gives me the error

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I'm positive ruby is installed in the virtual machine. I can run rails server by manually going inside my virtual machine going to my SampleApp folder and running `rails server` there and everything works fine. But for some reason when I put all that in a shell script. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got to initialize RVM in your script first. Try putting this line in:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

You might also need to specify a gemset, if you're using something other than the default:

```
rvm use @mygemset
```

See [the RVM scripting docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell script, you've reset your path to only include /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin.     ruby is usually installed somewhere like /usr/local/bin

instead you could concatenate that directory onto the end of your existing path.

something like:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0.p482/bin